# Where is the PHP log file located on Mac OSX?

Tags: mac, php, phpmyadmin

I am having issues with phpMyAdmin on my Mac.  I cannot seem to connect to the local MySQL server. When I try to log in I get the following message

```
Cannot start session without errors, please check errors given in your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly.
```

I am now trying to find the log file.  I ran `phpinfo()` and it tells me that the `php.ini` file is located in `/etc`, however when I look I only can see `php.ini.default`. I proceed to edit `php.ini.default` by specifying the log file to `/tmp/php_errors` and enable logging.

I tried to log into the MySQL server via phpMyAdmin and I still get the same error.  I proceed to `/tmp` but the error log is not there.

Any suggestions on what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try renaming `php.ini.default` to `php.ini` and edit it to enable the logging you want.

The changes probably won't take effect until Apache is restarted.  Since you are using a Mac, just disable web sharing and re-enable it.

Comment: credit goes to Bandit. My phpinfo() showed that "log_errors" was "Off", even though it was set to "on" in my 'php.ini.default'. After I changed the name of that file to 'php.ini' and did a restart of apache, my error log was indeed showing errors correctly, and my phpinfo() showed "log_errors" was "On".

Answer (score 28):

Apache's logs are located under `/var/log/apache2`

Comment: When a location isn't specified in php.ini, the PHP error log does seem to be found in /var/log/apache2/error_log by default. Thanks.

Comment: I have a custom apache install, so I found my log files with `find /usr/local -name error_log` .